# How do I include a file with a puppet manifest?

Tags: puppet

I have a very simple use for `puppet`; I create and delete students from a test server. I would like to store some configuration variables in another file and then just do a simple: `include 'variables.pp'` at the top of my manifest file. Is there a simple way to do this? I have consulted:

https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_classes.html#using-include
https://puppet.com/blog/problem-separating-data-from-puppet-code

None of which give a simple solution. If I can only use the solutions above, I'll just hardcode it in my manifest.

Comment: This is a good use case for external facts: https://docs.puppet.com/facter/3.1/custom_facts.html#external-facts. I recommend a yaml file with key-value pairs for your specific scenario. I can make this a full answer with some more info from you.

Comment: Which version of Puppet are you using?  Are you using `puppet apply` or `puppet agent`?

Comment: @JohnBollinger: I am using 3.4.* (I forget which patch version). Yes, I am using `puppet apply`.

Comment: @MattSchuchard That would be great if you can make a full answer. I'm familiar with yams files. Does the key simply become a ruby variable that I can access in the scope of my manifest? The link you gave doesn't make it clear. Also, is there a way to reference a fact that I have stored in the current working directory? Again, my setup is very simple so I don't want to have to put files in other non-related directories.

Comment: @Avery John Bollinger's answer will serve you well. It is not best practices for your problem, but it will get the job done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puppet 3 has an `import` statement that should serve your purpose.  It is deprecated (and removed from Puppet 4), but it will do the job for you in Puppet 3:

---

**variables.pp**

```
# top-scope variables:
$var1 = 'foo'
$var2 = 'bar'
```

**main.pp**

```
import 'variables.pp'

# demo
notify { "var1 = ${var1}; var2 = ${var2}": }
```

---

Note that Puppet's `import` does not perform text interpolation; it is more like Python's `import`, making complete declarations from another manifest visible in the importing manifest.

Comment: The "import" keyword has been deprecated. Please see https://serverfault.com/questions/685453/what-to-use-instead-of-import-keyword

Comment: Yes, @Saustin, as this answer already says.  And the OP (over three years ago) was using already-obsolete Puppet 3, so that doesn't seem so relevant an issue, particularly since in that version, `import` does exactly what they asked for, and nothing else does, in that or any later version.